# I can't connect to database in MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I just started learning react, mongodb, nodejs and express. i can't connect to mongodb in a small project please help

This is my code, terminal screen and mongod., Client is a react folder and server is a connection folder.
[image]

Comment: Does `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/denemeform', ...` fix the immediate problem?

Comment: check mongod.conf file that the mongodb server is configured to allow connections from your machine.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: @Kanish He tries to connect to `localhost`, thus your comment does not make any sense.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit go it, localhost is always allowed to connect to mongodb, so no need to check the mongod.conf file.